# Populate JSP Form

Tags: java, jsp

How to populate a form when JSP is called first time ? I need to process an XML file when a page is refreshed & populate the form in the JSP page?(not using frameworks)

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 options:

1. Use `<jsp:usebean>`, let the bean fill itself in the constructor.

   ```
   <jsp:useBean id="bean" class="com.example.Bean" />
   ...
   <input name="foo" value="${fn:escapeXml(bean.foo)}">
   <input name="bar" value="${fn:escapeXml(bean.bar)}">
   ```

   The `fn:escapeXml()` is not mandatory for the functioning, but it's mandatory to prevent XSS attacks if you're redisplaying user-controlled input in a HTML page.
2. Use the `doGet()` method of a Servlet.

   ```
   Bean bean = new Bean();
   request.setAttribute("bean", bean);
   request.getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp").forward(request, response);
   ```

   and use the URL to servlet in browser address bar instead of the JSP's one. You can use the same code in JSP page as above, expect of the `jsp:useBean` line.

Way 1 is more the oldschool and student's way. Way 2 is more MVC oriented and preferred in this particular case since you seem to be doing more than just populating a bean.

#### See also:

- [JSP tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) - contains useful tutorial links at bottom

Answer (score 0):

Sure - just set initial values in the bean properties that you are exposing in your form. Then use expression language to populate the fields, such as

`<input type="text" value="${bean.myProperty}"/>`